# Error updating Wcf message before hitting service using IDispatchOperationSelector

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

We are having to intercept a SOAP message before it hits our WCF service to perform the following steps:

- Route the message to the correct method as the client is unable to provide us with a SOAPAction value.
- Update the namespaces of the xml as the client is unable to add namespace information to the message.

The routing is not an issue, but we are having a problem with creating the message; once we recreate the message the body merely consists of "... Stream ...".

Before creating the message, the messageContent variable contains valid, correct xml.

```
private Message UpdateNamespaces(Message message, string methodName)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream);
        message.WriteMessage(xmlWriter);
        xmlWriter.Flush();

        var messageContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        xmlWriter.Close();

        // Update messageContent with corrected XML

        memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageContent));
        var xmlDictionaryReader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(memoryStream, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
        var newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(xmlDictionaryReader, int.MaxValue, message.Version);
        newMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(message.Properties);

        return newMessage;
    }
```

The messageContent is correct at the point at which we create the memoryStream, but as soon as I check the content of newMessage.ToString(), I'm getting the "... Stream ..." body content.

If anyone could help, I'd be very grateful as I'm out of ideas!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing behavior responsibilities.

`IDispatchOperationSelector.SelectOperation` is intended for routing decisions. It gives you a reference to the message, but the intention is to enable access to message properties. WCF does not expect the you to modify the message using this extension point. I can't say definitively, but the problem could be that simple.

If you want to alter the message namespace you should be using [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx). I suggest creating a second behavior for that task. Here's a nice [Message Inspector example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/19/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your response; I've now moved the functionality to a class inheriting from the IDispatchMessageInspector as suggested. I was however, still getting the same issue. It turns out that it's to do with the message only being able to be "read" once and I think some logging was causing a read. The example you suggested helped loads; thanks again!